# Python 2.7, trying to find unique numbers from list of integers

Tags: python-2.7

I have to find unique integers from list of integers Node1ID ,containing over 80000 integer values. I have following code that works. However it is very slow. Takes over 5 minutes to execute. Looking for a faster way . Can somebody help?

Here is my code:

```
output = []
for x in Node1ID:
    if x not in output:
        output.append(x)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `set` from the list, then convert that back to a list.

```
output = list(set(Node1D))
```

Sets cannot contain duplicate elements, so the first conversion gets rid of all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind Looks like I just got it

answer is following

```
import numpy as np
unique=np.unique([Node1ID])
```

executes in less than 0.1 seconds

thanks